# compizconfig-settings-manager: command not found

Tags: unity, apt, package-management, compiz, add-apt-repository

When I start compizconfig-settings-manager, I get the message *command not found*, but apt-get says that it is installed.

Searching for the reason, I found that compizconfig-settings-manager was updated in the last system update, the log says "compizconfig-settings-manager:amd64 (0.9.5.92-0ubuntu3, 0.9.8+bzr3287-0linaro3)". There (and also in many other entries) appears this **linaro**, which seems to be the problem. Because few days ago, I added a repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay
```

Now I wanted to remove it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay
```

But it failed with the message (no module named Linaro). I found another way to remove this repository: I deleted the file for this repository in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

I thought now I could just make a system update to get back the old packages, but the update manager says that all my packages are the newest version. So how can I get rid of those linaro-packages?

Answer (score 0):

Two commands - one to add the PPA - the other to revert back to official packages and to remove it again:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay
sudo ppa-purge ppa:linaro-maintainers/overlay
```